# Enron Email Dataset in MySQL

Tags: data-request, sql, email

For the purpose of my research, I need the Enron Email Dataset. According to the [project's official website](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E./enron/), there is an archive of emails represented in the set of separate TXT files, but the problem is this archive is not well organized and requires a lot of preparation work in order to be able to proceed with the data.

I looked for some ready-to-use well-organized archive of Enron Email Dataset in MySQL, but the only collection I found is the dump of MySQL database, which contains only two columns — message ID and content, no sender/receiver column, and no title column. My question is there any well and completely organized Enron Email Dataset in MySQL database format, where I can execute some SQL queries according to sender/receiver, where it is easy to retrieve a message title etc.

Comment: So, let's move the question to this community. Should I do it manually (create new & delete old) or moderators can just move the question between the sites?

Comment: I believe only moderators can move posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some additional search, I found the worked link among of lots, which point to 404 pages.
The worked ones are:
— https://s3.amazonaws.com/rjurney_public_web/images/enron.mysql.5.5.20.sql.gz
— http://www.ahschulz.de/pub/R/data/enron-mysqldump_v5.sql.gz

Detailed information about these datasets:
— http://hortonworks.com/blog/the-data-lifecycle-part-one-avroizing-the-enron-emails/
— http://www.ahschulz.de/enron-email-data/

P.S. Don't know why, but for me the download process was very slow.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for finding this, with the coding example.  Will help me, too.

Comment: Could you please include details about what columns these datasets have? Thanks!

Comment: Detailed information about one of the collection: http://www.ahschulz.de/enron-email-data/

Comment: Two more:  

- [UC Berkeley Enron Email Analysis](http://bailando.sims.berkeley.edu/enron_email.html)
- [Enron by Joel Pfeiffer from Purdue](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jpfeiff/enron.html)

Comment: Do you by any chance know if the emails in this data set contain fields like "hasReplied" or "hasForwarded"? For evaluation purpose I require the information if a user has replied or forwarded a particular message - is this in the data set?

Comment: @displayname , unfortunately, I don't remember. But you can download the files and check it, it's one-minute check.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to create an SQL DB by using FERC Enron XERA web application: http://fercenron.omega-caci.com/default.html ([user guide](http://www.ferc.gov/industries/electric/indus-act/wec/xera/enron-xera-user-guide-032813.pdf)).

You'd use the search feature of XERA based on fields, and then export the result to a delimited file, then convert to SQL database for additional queries.

Comment: You could also look at this: http://orchestrate.io/blog/2014/07/17/using-orchestrates-graph-search-with-the-enron-emails/